# cloning MySQL database using mysqldump

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to copy my database with a different name. I've found this:

```
$ mysqldump yourFirstDatabase -u user -ppassword > yourDatabase.sql
$ mysql yourSecondDatabase -u user -ppassword < yourDatabase.sql
```

But I do not understand clearly.
So I have 2 databases: lab1, lab2. lab2 contains 0 tables since I want this to be a copy of lab1.
So 'lab1' is 'yourFirstDatabase' and lab2 is 'yourSecondDatabase', right? then what is 'yourDatabase?' 
Also I got the error below:

```
$ mysqldump -uroot lab1 -u user -ppassword > yourDatabase.sql;
```

> mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface
>   can be insecure. mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user
>   'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect

Comment: is your user `root` or `user`? You need to decide ;-)

Comment: oh it's user now

Comment: `yourDatabase.sql` is the file you're writing to / reading from.  The filename doesn't have to match the source / target database for your command to work, it just has to be the same filename for both commands.

Answer (score 2):

process work just like you said.For yourDatabese you are creating a temporary backup file that is used only for transferring yourFirstDatabase